# how to unregister a messenger event - Galasoft MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

### Environment;

WPF, Galasoft MVVM Light

I have a scenario where many in-active xaml views of my application keep listening to a messenger's message and this makes my application to work very slow.

### Question;

What is the best way to unregister a message from inactive view? I want only active instance of a view to listen messages.

I tried to unregister it on unloading event of a view, but this unregister it from active instance also.

Thanks,
Asif

Answer (score 0):

Events aren't expensive, it's the code you execute when the event has been received.
(Re)Design your message event receivers so that they only execute when the view is active.